# PieChartView not appearing on the screen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to display pie chart programmatically but I am unable to do that.
here is the code.

```
// Create pie chart view
let pieChart: PieChartView = {
    let pieChart = PieChartView()
    pieChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pieChart.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    return pieChart
}()

setPieChartData(chartView: pieChart, labels: labels, values: values)
        
setupViews() // Here I am adding the piechart view as follows
view.addSubview(pieChart)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    pieChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 180),
    pieChart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20)])
        
pieChart.setNeedsDisplay()


func setPieChartData(chartView: PieChartView, labels: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var entries: [PieChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<labels.count {
        entries.append(PieChartDataEntry(value: values[i], label: labels[i]))
    }
    let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Pie Chart")
    dataSet.colors = [.orange, .red]
//    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true // Hide values on chart
//    
//    // Set additional properties for donut chart
//    dataSet.drawIconsEnabled = true
//    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
//    dataSet.sliceSpace = 2.0 // Adjust space between slices to create donut effect
            
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
    chartView.data = data
}
```

What am I missing?

I tried adding background color and changed the constraints but it is not working.

Comment: If you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, do not also try to use `autoresizingMask`. The biggest issue is that you are missing constraints. Unless the `PieChartView` class provides an intrinsic size, your constraints need to provide a width and height, or the trailing and top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `pieChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, `pieChart.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]` will be useless. You need to set the constraints yourself, like:

```swift
pieChart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
pieChart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
```

But based on your `topAnchor` & `leadingAnchor`, I guess you need `trailingAnchor` & `bottomAnchor`:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  pieChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 180),
  pieChart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
  pieChart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
  pieChart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Comment: It makes sense also, one issue was I had to add width and height and the it worked.

Comment: Yep, of course it is. The point is just to make sure you provide enough constraints when setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, just like @HangarRash said, _"It all depends on how you want the chart to be constrained."_

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
 pieChart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
 pieChart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
```

Add width and height solved the issue.

Comment: This is of course in addition to the two existing constraints for top and leading. Or replace these width and height constraints with trailing and bottom constraints, like in the other answer. It all depends on how you want the chart to be constrained.